# SAPUI5 sam.m.Input.submit() does not work

Tags: model-view-controller, input, submit, sapui5

Currently I want to create a function to handle when user press `Enter` on `Input field (sap.m.Input)`. I found this suitable function `submit()` in the API.

However it didn't work, I tried but nothing happen. I pressed enter but it does not call the responding function.

Here my code:

**App.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Test.controller.App" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <Input submit='onSubmit'/>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

**App.controller.js:**

```
 sap.ui.define([
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
    ], function(Controller) {
        "use strict";


        return Controller.extend("Test.controller.App", {
            onSubmit: function(oEvent){
                console.log("Submitted");
            }


        });


    });
```

I pressed enter but nothing showed in the console.

I'm looking for help from your expert experience. Is the submit() function does not work anymore? Is there another function to solve my question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `submit` is not a function, it's an event.

> This event is fired when user presses the Enter key on the input.

So, function to be called when event is fired should be specified as this event's value in *view*.

View code:

```
<Input submit='onSubmit'/>
```

Controller code:

```
onSubmit: function(oEvent) {
     console.log("Submitted");
 }
```